# ActionBarSherlock AndroidManifest.xml and other files missing on import

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'd like to try the ActionBarSherlock library, but no matter what I try either my project gets the red exclamation point, or sherlock gets the red exclamation point, or sherlock gets errors, or I get "[2011-11-09 18:59:29 - Library-ActionBarSherlock] AndroidManifest.xml file missing!", etc...

I constantly open, close, clean, "fix project properties".  I've tried it on the app i actually want to use it on and ive tried it with a brand new project with nothing else in the workspace but the library.

I really don't know what to try or what I'm doing wrong to make it seem so finicky.

EDIT:
for example, right now sherlock has a red x with the missing manifest error and my project has a red exclamation point and when i go to build path the error is "actionbarsherlock.jar - ...(missing)".

EDIT2:
I've looked many place including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132204/greendroid-or-actionbarsherlock-setup), [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/79#issuecomment-2464701), [here](http://groups.google.com/group/actionbarsherlock/browse_thread/thread/9fceab134891bdcf/f9253b4cf6964f61?show_docid=f9253b4cf6964f61), and [here](https://groups.google.com/group/actionbarsherlock/browse_thread/thread/709d2055a474e2d1#).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fixed. Following note made by Gintautas Miliauskas Dec 10 '10 at 15:46 on [this web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404553/missing-androidmanifest-xml-when-importing-an-old-android-project-into-eclipse). So basically copy the source to a folder outside the Eclipse workspace, Create Android Project from Existing Source with the source being the library folder. This clears the missing AndroidManifest.xml error. After than the project can be moved to the workspace through Right Click > Refactor > Move

Having fixed the missing AndroidManifest.xml file - now getting erorrs : 
The type ActionMenuItem must implement the inherited abstract method MenuItem.expandActionView()ActionMenuItem.java 
/ActionBarSherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu line 11 Java Problem

Loads of these errors. Will start to look into them. Also Cannot instantiate the type MenuItemWrapper ActionBarWrapper.java. These went away after changing ActionBarSherlock to switch from Android 4.0 to Android 3.2.

Comment: You have to implement 4 additional methods in `MenuItemImpl` and `MenuItemWrapper` in order to compile with Android 4.0+

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that when you bring in the project, your target API is 3.2. It will not work with any other target API. I recently struggled with this exact problem

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when I first tried installing ActionBarSherlock.

My solution was to

1. Completely remove all ActionBarSherlock files/folder
2. Update Eclipse (Help -> Check for updates)
3. Re-download ActionBarSherlock
4. Unpack it to a folder **outside** my Eclipse workspace.
5. Do the File -> New Android Project -> from existing source, **using com_actionbarsherlock as the project name (first time I used ActionBarSherlock).**
6. Change my app project to target API version 15
7. Import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you are having trouble importing Sherlock library to ecliple and getting missing manifest and other files then **I have a simple workaround**.

I am not sure why this is happening. But now I am able to solve this on all my machines.

Basically we are going to import same project using Android import and then eclipse import.

1. Add project to Eclipse by going to **File >> New Project >> `Android Project`**
2. Select `existing project from existing source` and select the folder `Your-Sherlock-Project-Path/library`, continue and hit Finish.
3. You will **get errors, missing Manifest and more** ...
4. Now go to File >> Import and select `import existing file system` Select the same folder from step 2. Make sure your `into folder` is from Step 2
5. Tick overwrite all files.
6. That is it .... Thanks :P

Cheers.

Comment: Could you be more specific on step #4 `Select the same folder from step 1` is this just the `ActionBarSherlock->library` folder?

Comment: Edited, @Wallter hope its helpful.