# how to setup ActionBarSherlock?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I would like to use the library ActionBarSherlock in one of my projects, but I get errors all over the place when I create a project as a library with sources!

I followed the instructions correctly, as shown here for example: [Greendroid or ActionbarSherlock - setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132204/greendroid-or-actionbarsherlock-setup)

But I get many errors like:

```
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found That matches the given name 'android: Theme.Holo.Light' in abs__styles.xml
```

Comment: I get this same problem happening too. Also, this question should not be closed. The errors happening are very clear ("Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'."), as well as the steps that were followed to reproduce.

Comment: I finally managed to use ActionBar sherlock, I have in my manifest:
`code`<application
         android: icon = "@ drawable / ic_launcher"
         android: label = "@ string / app_name"
         android: theme = "@ style / Theme.SherlockClient">`code`
and in my file style.xml
`code`<style name="Theme.SherlockClient" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock"> ... </ style>`code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the official [usage page](http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html) and the sample projects that come with the source, using third-party tutorials is not always a good idea. If you still have problems post concrete errors and stack traces. Also consider posting on the project's [official Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/actionbarsherlock), you have a better chance of getting help there.

Comment: I have already thought of that, unfortunately, but as the library does not work either demos

Comment: Really? The official group has a lot info, someone even made a youtube video on how to set it up, check it out. Other than that, make sure you are compiling with API level 13 (Android 3.2) and you've properly added the library project. Using the latest ADT version (16) also helps.